# Start a batch file silently from the autorun.inf

Tags: batch, autorun, silent-install

Is it possible to start a batch file silently with no window created from the autorun.inf?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Sounds like you're trying to start stuff on someone else's machine you don't want them knowing about (malicious?).
Even so, IIRC, Microsoft patched some things in the autorun functionality so that it always shows all items, so I don't think it is possible.

Comment: No, I want to start a batch that starts an autorun according whether the .net is installed (e.g. autorun.net.exe autorun.old.exe).

Comment: I found a free tool NirCmd on  http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html that can start a batch silently, but I want to start my batch directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would probably have to do is code the autorun.exe (or whatever you want your .inf to start automatically) such that the first thing it does is to detect whether .NET is installed.  If it is, it runs the executable that supports .NET.  If it isn't, it runs a separate executable for no .NET.  That's about as close as you're going to come.  There's no way to do it within the .INF file.